# Select doctrine config after login on Zend 1.11

Tags: database, authentication, doctrine

everybody! I'm doing an application with several databases where each one belongs to one specific department.

So, I have on my Bootstrap.php the method _initDoctrine() that initialize the connection with DB (meanwhile, i have only one).

```
public function _initDoctrine() {
    $this->getApplication()->getAutoloader()
            ->pushAutoloader(array('Doctrine', 'autoload'));
    spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine', 'modelsAutoload'));


    $manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();
    $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE, true);
    $manager->setAttribute(
            Doctrine::ATTR_MODEL_LOADING, Doctrine::MODEL_LOADING_CONSERVATIVE
    );
    $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_AUTOLOAD_TABLE_CLASSES, true);

    $doctrineConfig = $this->getOption('doctrine');

    Doctrine::loadModels($doctrineConfig['models_path']);

    $conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection($doctrineConfig['dsn'], 'doctrine');
    $conn->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_USE_NATIVE_ENUM, true);
    return $conn;
}
```

In my login page, there's 3 options (databases) which the user will choose to connect.
So, there's anyway to init doctrine config after login??

PS: sorry my english